# Web API vs. Remote API - What are the differences, or are they the same?

Tags: webapi, remoteapi

Wikipedia says:

A **Web API** is [an application programming interface for a web server (or web browser)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API). And a **Remote API** is an application programming interface that [allows developers to manipulate remote resources through protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API#Remote_APIs).

So, since Web APIs (e.g., Twitter APIs) are code snippets that developers use in their apps to access a web server's resource (via the HTTP protocol). Does this mean that a Web API is the same as a Remote API?

Or, are there any subtle differences?

Answer (score 0):

A `Web API` is a type of `Remote API` that uses the HTTP protocol to manipulate resources. We have many other communication networks, but the one used by `Web APIs` is the internet, which makes use of the HTTP protocol.